How to link ODB library to project correctly using cmake in Windows?
I have used vcpkg to install rapidjson and curl but I am finding it difficult to link the ODB library for PostgreSQL to my project
I have built the required libraries using instructions from this link
I'm using vscode with the VS2022 toolkit. I have the odb-pgsql-d-2.4-vc12.dll and odb-d-2.4-vc12.dll in the PATH and the project directory.
I was able to generate the xxx-odb.hpp files using the ODB compiler but I am not able to link the library correctly seems like?
Attaching a minimal CMakeLists.txt, main.cpp and the build output file.
I get unresolved external symbol errors.
CMakeLists.txt
project(main VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

set(CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM x64)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

set(VCPKG_INSTALLED_DIR "C:\\vcpkg\\installed\\x64-windows")
set(ODB_COMPILER_PATH "C:\\pathtools\\bin")
set(ODB_INSTALLED_DIR "C:\\external")

find_package(PostgreSQL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE PostgreSQL::PostgreSQL)

find_program(ODB_COMPILER NAMES odb PATHS "${ODB_COMPILER_PATH}" EXTERNAL REQUIRED)
set(ODB_LIB_DIR "${ODB_INSTALLED_DIR}/lib")
set(ODB_INCLUDE_DIR "${ODB_INSTALLED_DIR}/include")
target_include_directories(main PRIVATE ${ODB_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${ODB_LIB_DIR})
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE ${ODB_LIB_DIR}/odb-d.lib)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE ${ODB_LIB_DIR}/odb-pgsql-d.lib)

add_custom_target(run
    COMMAND ${PROJECT_NAME}
    DEPENDS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_PROJECT_DIR}
)

main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <odb/pgsql/database.hxx>
#include <odb/transaction.hxx>

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<odb::pgsql::database> db(new odb::pgsql::database("postgres", "password", "maindb", "localhost", 5432));
    return 0;
}

Build logs
[main] Building folder: c:/main/build main
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/main/build --config Debug --target main -j 22 --
[build] MSBuild version 17.11.9+a69bbaaf5 for .NET Framework
[build] 
[build] main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall odb::pgsql::database::database(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class odb::details::transfer_ptr<class odb::pgsql::connection_factory>)" (__imp_??0database@pgsql@odb@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@000I0V?$transfer_ptr@Vconnection_factory@pgsql@odb@@@details@2@@Z) referenced in function _main [C:\main\build\main.vcxproj]
[build] main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall odb::pgsql::database::~database(void)" (__imp_??1database@pgsql@odb@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __thiscall odb::pgsql::database::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_Gdatabase@pgsql@odb@@UAEPAXI@Z) [C:\main\build\main.vcxproj]
[build] main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class odb::pgsql::transaction_impl * __thiscall odb::pgsql::database::begin(void)" (?begin@database@pgsql@odb@@UAEPAVtransaction_impl@23@XZ) [C:\main\build\main.vcxproj]
[build] main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual struct odb::database::schema_version_info const & __thiscall odb::pgsql::database::load_schema_version(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)const " (?load_schema_version@database@pgsql@odb@@MBEABUschema_version_info@13@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) [C:\main\build\main.vcxproj]
[build] main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class odb::connection * __thiscall odb::pgsql::database::connection_(void)" (?connection_@database@pgsql@odb@@MAEPAVconnection@3@XZ) [C:\main\build\main.vcxproj]
[build] C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\lib\libpq.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86' [C:\main\build\main.vcxproj]
[build] C:\external\lib\odb-d.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86' [C:\main\build\main.vcxproj]
[build] C:\external\lib\odb-pgsql-d.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86' [C:\main\build\main.vcxproj]
[build] C:\main\build\Debug\main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals [C:\main\build\main.vcxproj]
[proc] The command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/main/build --config Debug --target main -j 22 -- exited with code: 1
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:01.946
[build] Build finished with exit code 1


There are several issues in your build environment.
odb-pgsql-d-2.4-vc12.dll and odb-d-2.4-vc12.dll and their import libraries are for Visual Studio 2013 and are likely not compatible with Visual Studio 2022. You may need either to downgrade Visual Studio or upgrade ODB libraries that mention the version vc17.

warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'

Is a bit more obvious. The main target platform is x86 and the ODB libraries target x64. They are not compatible. You have not shown how you run cmake, perhaps with -A Win32, you should not set it or use -A x64.
